# Reading Basic (VBDOS) Random Acces Files in under PHP

Tags: php, basic

I want to read random access files of made by software written in VBDOS. (not using MBF)

Reading the file is straightforward, and text stored in the files is readable.

My problem is that data that comes from Singles, Doubles, Integers and Floats is stored encoded into the file with MKx or read and decoded with CVx. (for a single MKS and CVS, for doubles MKD and CVD, etc)

I want to read some of these files in PHP (and as written above, stored strings do not give a problem.)

I would like to know what the functions MKx and CVx actually do  so I can duplicate this functionality. 
Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The floating-point encoding format used by GWBasic is called [Microsoft Binary Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Binary_Format), or MBF.  The Wikipedia page has links to some conversion functions in [C](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_20245266.html) and [Python](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Python/comp.lang.python/2005-08/msg03951.html).  Based on those you should be able to implement something equivalent in PHP.

Comment: I think I made it unclear. The programs were originaly written gwbasic, and later in VBDos. The MBF format is not used in these files. I adapted the question.